# Why do listboxes and treeviews load large amounts of data so slowly?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

Well the question is relative to a DataGrid.

I have a table in a MySQL database. It has about 20 columns and stores about 32 thousand records.

So I normally load these in my test apps using a DataGrid and it usually takes two seconds or less for it to populate all the information with no lazy loading. (EF 6)

So I really just need one column and decided to use a ListView. Thing is I've only ever used it with very small tables so the lag wasn't even worth mentioning. Likewise with a TreeView.

It baffles me how a DataGrid can handle all this information almost seamlessly while the ListBox seems to feel the need to reload the contents with every change of selection using the arrow keys. It's only loading one column really.

It takes ages to load as soon as the UserControl is initialized and I'm thinking maybe it's me not optimizing my code properly. Perhaps the two are to be treated differently?

This is the XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Principal, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="first" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyCHanged}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Width="Auto"/>
```

And in the View Model, this is the property it's DataBound to:

```
    // Private ObservableCollection Declaration
    private ObservableCollection<principal> _principal;

    // Public ObservableCollection Declaration
    public ObservableCollection<principal> Principal
    {
        get
        {
            return _principal;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_principal != value)
            {
                value = _principal;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("Principal");
        }
    }
```

That's pretty much it. My DataGrid binds to the exact same property with very similar XAML code but it will load all the columns in a tenth of the time it would take a Listbox or TreeView.

I've been at it for a while now but it just doesn't check out.
Anyone know why?

Comment: use WPF performance suite do understand what takes time. There's no reason why `ListBox` should perform worse than `DataGrid`.

Comment: My best guess is its not using virtualization, so it is rendering the XAML for every single row instead of only for the visible rows. Double-check that you are limiting your ListBox to a specific height, and perhaps try enabling Virtualization manually

Comment: Who wants to see 32k records at once? I'd say filtering is an issue here not the performance ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I find ListBox and ListView to be very fast.

Try

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

Are you by any chance not constraining the size?
If you don't constrain the size then it will paint all the elements.